# Self-dual simplicial complexes

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, simplicial-complexes

A simplicial complex $K$ on a vertex set $[m] = \{1,...,m \}$ - where here we say vertex set to mean an ambient set of vertices on which $K$ is defined - is self-dual if it is equal to its Alexander dual $\widehat{K}$, where $\widehat{K}$ is the simplicial complex on $[m]$ whose simplices are the complements of the missing faces of $K$. That is, simplices of $\widehat{K}$ are given by
$$\widehat{K} = \{J \subseteq [m] \; | \; [m] \backslash J \notin K \}.$$

An example of a self dual complex is $\partial \Delta^2$ disjoint unioned with one vertex: $K = \{\emptyset, \{ 1\} \{2 \} \{ 3\} \{ 4\} \{ 1,2\} \{2,3 \} \{ 1,3\} \}$.

Timotejević's [2019 note](http://www.vesnik.math.rs/vol/mv191208.pdf) explores the combinatorial structure of such complexes. For example, theorem 2.4 therein says that a complex $K$ is self dual if and only if for arbitrary $A \subseteq [m]$, $A \in K \iff [m] \backslash A \notin K$.

One may also define a simplicial complex to be self-dual if it is *isomorphic*, as a simplicial complex, to its Alexander dual. With this definition, the above theorem does not hold. For example, consider the simplicial complex on four vertices $$K = \{\emptyset, \{ 1\} \{2 \} \{ 3\} \{ 4\} \{ 1,2\} \{2,3 \} \{ 3,4\} \}.$$
This is isomorphic to its Alexander dual $\widehat{K} = \{\emptyset, \{ 1\} \{2 \} \{ 3\} \{ 4\} \{ 1,2\} \{1,3 \} \{ 2,4\} \}$, and is therefore self-dual in this sense.

What is known about self-dual complexes in the second sense? What is known about their combinatorial structure?

Comment: Note that one thing that makes this a little unnatural is that it depends on $m$.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your remarks. When I have been saying "vertex set", I have always meant an ambient set on which my complex is defined, rather than the singleton simplices in my complex. I'll edit my question to clarify my meaning.

Comment: I'm going to delete my other comments because they were getting a bit repetitive, and my first comment is really the point.